Function to identify unique values and input in a function in R
This is what part of my function looks like:
function_test <- function(x) {
fa_dataset <- test_survey %>% 
  filter(Tenure_Category == x) %>% 
  dplyr::select(c(Proud:Respect)) %>% 
  drop_na()

cor_mat_tenure <- cor(fa_dataset)

}

function_test("0-1 Yr")
function_test("1-2 Yr")
function_test("2-5 Yr")


I have a dataset with n columns, one column within my dataset 'test_survey' is 'Tenure_Category'. This column has 7 distinct values: 0-1 Yr, 1-2 Yr, 2-5 Yr, 5-10 Yr, 10-15 Yr, 15-20 Yr, 20+ Yr.
I would like to add to the code. I want the function to identify these distinct values and then input them in the filter statement, one by one. I don't want to specify an argument in the function manually (as I did above).
I am thinking that a for-loop would be a better choice, something like:
for(i in 1:length(unique(test_survey$Tenure_Category))){
   fa_dataset <- test_survey %>% 
   filter(Tenure_Category == test_survey[i]) %>%
   dplyr::select(c(Proud:Respect)) %>% 
   drop_na()

   cor_mat_tenure <- cor(fa_dataset)
 }

Needless to say, this code does not work.
Any help here would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Perhaps you're looking for split()?

@lotus, how do I use that here?

Try test_survey |>  select(Proud:Respect) |>  drop_na() |>  split(~Tenure_Category)

What is your desired output? A data frame, list, or something else?

A filtered dataframe

Do you mean a list of filtered data frames? If so, then lotus has given you the answer.

Your questions is lacking a reproducible example and it's lacking clarity. But if I understand correctly you want to filter your data frame by Tenure category and then calculate the correlation between Proud and Respect. Is that it? Also, I'm assuming you want to keep the results of each correlation while keeping the link to the Tenure category.
Below an example for the for loop solution. The only problem with your version is the way you filter the Tenure_Category, so I tried to keep it as similar to yours as possible
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# Creating a reproducible example
tenure_category <- c('0-1 Yr', '1-2 Yr', '2-5 Yr', '5-10 Yr', '10-15 Yr', '15-20 Yr', '20+ Yr')

tenure_category <- sample(tenure_category, 100, replace = TRUE) # creates a vector with 100 observations of strings in tenure category

proud <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)

respect <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)

test_survey <- data.frame(Tenure_Category = tenure_category, Proud = proud, Respect = respect)

names <- unique((tenure_category))

cor_l <- list() # list object to keep the resulting correlations
for (i in 1:length(names)){
  tmp <- df %>%
    filter(Tenure_Category == names[i]) %>% 
    select(Proud, Respect) %>%
    drop_na
  
  cor_l[[i]] <- cor(tmp)
  
  # Adding name to each list oject, so that you keep track of Tenure_Category
  names(cor_l)[i] <- names[i]
}

print(cor_l[1:2])
    
    print(cor_l[1:2])
    
    # $`15-20 Yr`
    # Proud   Respect
    # Proud   1.0000000 0.1439552
    # Respect 0.1439552 1.0000000
    # 
    # $`10-15 Yr`
    # Proud      Respect
    # Proud    1.000000000 -0.004051884
    # Respect -0.004051884  1.000000000

